# Magento 1.8.1.0 Reports only shows one option

Tags: magento-1.8, ce-1.8.1.0, reports

After 1.8.1.0 upgrade the reports feature only shows one reporting option: Reports > Sales > Paypal Settlement Option

No other reporting options are showing?

Comment: Did you flush the configuration cache? This sounds like the Report module is deactivated and only Paypal's Report is shown...

Comment: @Dan I'm glad your issue was resolved! Please accept the answer below to properly solve this question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you flush the configuration cache?

This sounds like the Report module is deactivated and only Paypal's Report is shown...